# Click event is triggered on once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am triggering click event on class `select2-search-choice-close` but I am able to trigger only first / one occurrence of class `select2-search-choice-close`.

Below is my html code.

```
<ul class="select2-choices" style="">  
    <li class="select2-search-choice">    
        <div>Insurance Broker</div>    
        <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-search-choice">    
        <div>Insurance Broker</div>
        <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>        
    </li>
    <li class="select2-search-choice">    
        <div>Other business </div>    
        <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-search-field">
        <label for="s2id_autogen1" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
        <input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen1" tabindex="0" style="width: 10px;" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-83" type="text">  
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery code:**

```
$( ".select2-search-choice" ).each(function( index ) {
    if($.trim($( this ).text()) != 'No, I am not in a business.') {
        $(".select2-search-choice-close").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: at when do you want the trigger.?

Comment: I am calling this trigger event when I am getting event `DOMNodeInserted`. @DhavalPurohit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the item relative to the looped elelment

```
$( ".select2-search-choice" ).each(function( index ) {
        if($.trim($( this ).text()) != 'No, I am not in a business.') {
            $(this).find(".select2-search-choice-close").trigger("click");
        }
});
```

demo:

```js
$(".select2-search-choice-close").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).prev().text());
});

$(".select2-search-choice").each(function(index) {
  if ($.trim($(this).text()) != 'No, I am not in a business.') {
    $(this).find(".select2-search-choice-close").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="select2-choices" style="">
  <li class="select2-search-choice">
    <div>Insurance Broker</div>
    <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="select2-search-choice">
    <div>No, I am not in a business.</div>
    <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="select2-search-choice">
    <div>Other business</div>
    <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="select2-search-field">
    <label for="s2id_autogen1" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
    <input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen1" tabindex="0" style="width: 10px;" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-83" type="text">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need a loop because I don't want to trigger a click event for each element having this class

Comment: for what element do you want to trigger exactly ?

Comment: @Akshay better question is what exactly to you want to do ?

Comment: class `select2-search-choice-close` under `li` and `parent` class not having text `No, I am not in a business.` see my updated question

Comment: Nope still class got triggered only once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131027/discussion-between-akshay-and-madalin-ivascu).